# Как добавить элемент в атрибут? Добавления изображения area title="*IMG*"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

А как можно добавить изображения в атрибут? 
А решения через Ява Скрипт а можно пример? 
Пожалуйста помогите. (СМОТРИТЕ СКРИНШОТ)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так понимаю речь идет о изменении ссылки на изображение, по каким действиям вас интересует?

Comment: Не могли бы вы четче сформулировать вопрос

Comment: если через jquery то можно вот так: $('img').attr('src', 'значение');    Если JS то document.getElementById("тут ID img").src = "значение";

Comment: В атрибут title  ты изображение ни как не засунешь...  Это обычная картинка, имитирующая title... Просто создай  невидимый блок, который при hover всплывает и все...

Comment: Если нужно отображать изображение из атрибута элемента при наведении можете добавить атрибут типа: <img data-himg="ссылка" src="ссылка" title=""> и обрабатывать её

Answer (score 0):

Есть уже готовые решения для JQuery:
https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content